# i want to append data in box not container using masonry Jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to add data in box with jquery and masonry but it's not adding right.

see the below pictures for detail.

[image: masonry jquery example]

[image: masonry jquery example 2]

Comment: you mean button shows partially

Answer (score 1):

Without having seen you code or anything, try updateting the masonry container on the click event.

Something like this:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
      $('#moreTextElement').slideToggle();
      $('#yourMansonryContainer').masonry('reload');
});
```

The reason for this is that masonry needs to know when a element has changed in size in order to correct the layout.

Comment: After reading your comment im pretty sure thats the issue. You need to reload masonry after the new data/element is added so it can recalculate where to position the elements since masonry uses absolute positioning to position the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the text in a `<p>`, and the button under the `</p>`. So when you have $(#button).click, you will append the new data to the p tag, not the div as a whole.

Comment: no, my problem is this below div not getting down. as you can see 1st image is showing data right without click on "view more" button. when i click on more button to append data he remove space between 1st and 2nd div. you can see in 2nd image.